# How do I calculate no of states in "Vacuum Cleaner World"

Tags: artificial-intelligence

How do I calculate no of states in "Vacuum Cleaner World" ,given the number of positions of the vacuum cleaner -- for example, in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXTEF.jpg), it's 2.

Comment: Where are you stuck?  That diagram *gives* you all 8 states.  This is basic combinatorics..

Comment: yes.. what I'm confused about is , if there are 3 positions ,how many states will be there? Thanks @Prune

Comment: Thanks a lot  ,Prune , it helps.

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 1):

There are three independent factors (none of them affects the existence or available choices of the others)

1. Vacuum is [left | right]
2. There [is | is not] dirt on left
3. There [is | is not] dirt on right

To get the count of combinations for independent events, you multiply:

2 choices x 2 choices x 2 choices => 8 combinations.